# Must Submit Form Twice To Populate Variable from POST when using SESSION

Tags: php, html, forms, session

The following code works as expected:

```
<?php
//filename is noproblem.php
//Assign each letter a ratio
$ratios = array(
'A' => 1,
'B' => 0.5
);

//Assign each letter a quantity retrieved from POST
$quantities = array(
                'A' => $_POST['AQuantity'],
                'B' => $_POST['BQuantity']
        );

//Assign each letter a value 
$values = array(
                'A' => ($ratios['A']*$quantities['A']),
                'B' => ($ratios['B']*$quantities['B'])
        );

echo "Quantity A = "; echo($quantities['A']); echo "<br>";
echo "Value A = "; echo($values['A']); echo "<br>";
echo "Quantity B = "; echo($quantities['B']); echo "<br>";
echo "Value B = "; echo($values['B']);
?>  

<html>
<form name="Quantities" action="noproblem.php" method="post">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Insert">
<br>                                    
Quantity for A<input type="text" name="AQuantity" size="4 "value="<?php if($_POST['AQuantity']>0) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['AQuantity']);} else {echo 0;} ?>">
<br>
Quantity for B<input type="text" name="BQuantity" size="4" value="<?php if($_POST['BQuantity']>0) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['BQuantity']);} else {echo 0;} ?>">
</form> 
</html>
```

However, the issue is that I need the Quantities and Values variables to later carry over into another PHP file that cannot contain anything but PHP code (JPGraph). This can be achieved by using the $_SESSION variable but then the form submission suddenly requires being pressed twice. The offending code:

```
<?php
//filename is problem.php
session_start();

//Assign each letter a ratio
$ratios = array(
'A' => 1,
'B' => 0.5
);


$_SESSION = array(
        //Assign each letter a quantity retrieved from POST
        'quantities' => array(
                'A' => $_POST['AQuantity'],
                'B' => $_POST['BQuantity']
        ),
        //Assign each letter a USD Value from API data and their respective quantities
        'values' => array(
                'A' => ($ratios['A']*$_SESSION['quantities']['A']),
                'B' => ($ratios['B']*$_SESSION['quantities']['B'])
        ));
echo "Quantity A = "; echo($_SESSION['quantities']['A']); echo "<br>";
echo "Value A = "; echo($_SESSION['values']['A']); echo "<br>";
echo "Quantity B = "; echo($_SESSION['quantities']['B']); echo "<br>";
echo "Value B = "; echo($_SESSION['values']['B']);
?>  

<html>
<form name="Quantities" action="problem.php" method="post">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Insert">
<br>                                    
Quantity for A<input type="text" name="AQuantity" size="4 "value="<?php if($_POST['AQuantity']>0) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['AQuantity']);} else {echo 0;} ?>">
<br>
Quantity for B<input type="text" name="BQuantity" size="4" value="<?php if($_POST['BQuantity']>0) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['BQuantity']);} else {echo 0;} ?>">
</form> 
</html>
```

I must not comprehend how the SESSION works so some enlightenment in this regard would be appreciated. Primarily I need to know how to fix the code to properly calculate on a single press of the button while using SESSION. A less than ideal solution that I know will work is to duplicate each needed variable into the $_SESSION array and use the non SESSION variables in the main body of this file. Surely there is a more elegant way than that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with $_SESSION but with function calls (in this case arra()).

You tried to invoke the first call to array() with values set just after it returns. So you're multiplicating with 0 the first time. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, however, this is not best practice, its just solves your problem:

```
<?php
//filename is problem.php
session_start();

//Assign each letter a ratio
$ratios = array(
'A' => 1,
'B' => 0.5
);
$quantities = array(
                'A' => $_POST['AQuantity'],
                'B' => $_POST['BQuantity']
        );

//Assign each letter a value 
$values = array(
                'A' => ($ratios['A']*$quantities['A']),
                'B' => ($ratios['B']*$quantities['B'])
        );

$_SESSION['quantities'] = $quantities;
$_SESSION['values'] = $values;

echo "Quantity A = "; echo($_SESSION['quantities']['A']); echo "<br>";
echo "Value A = "; echo($_SESSION['values']['A']); echo "<br>";
echo "Quantity B = "; echo($_SESSION['quantities']['B']); echo "<br>";
echo "Value B = "; echo($_SESSION['values']['B']);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I alluded to this "solution" in my original post. I am aware that it works but it seems quite redundant and it still does not elucidate to me how SESSION works (or not).

Comment: session works one its set, it's not like cookie, you can access $_SESSION['quantities'] in other pages, but don't forget to call `session_start()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you could do something like this:

```
<?php
//filename is noproblem.php
//Assign each letter a ratio
$ratios = array(
'A' => 1,
'B' => 0.5
);

if ( !empty($_POST) ) {
   //Assign each letter a quantity retrieved from POST
   $_SESSION['quantities'] = array(
                'A' => intval($_POST['AQuantity']),
                'B' => intval($_POST['BQuantity'])
        );

   //Assign each letter a value 
   $_SESSION['values'] = array(
                'A' => ($ratios['A'] * $_SESSION['quantities']['A']),
                'B' => ($ratios['B'] * $_SESSION['quantities']['B'])
        );

   echo "Quantity A = "; echo($_SESSION['quantities']['A']); echo "<br>";
   echo "Value A = "; echo($_SESSION['values']['A']); echo "<br>";
   echo "Quantity B = "; echo($_SESSION['quantities']['B']); echo "<br>";
   echo "Value B = "; echo($_SESSION['values']['B']);
}
?>  

<html>
<form name="Quantities" action="noproblem.php" method="post">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Insert">
<br>                                    
Quantity for A<input type="text" name="AQuantity" size="4 "value="<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['quantities']['A'])) {echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['quantities']['A']);} else {echo 0;} ?>">
<br>
Quantity for B<input type="text" name="BQuantity" size="4" value="<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['quantities']['B'])) {echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['quantities']['B']);} else {echo 0;} ?>">
</form> 
</html>
```

This sets the SESSION values and then uses them if they are not empty. Notice that I wrapped your POST values in intval() to enforce a number also. Not sure if this will help, but here is a [session tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). Assuming you use session_start() in your next PHP script, the variables you set here should be availabe.

Comment: The session variables will be set correctly on form post as pointed out by @6bb6. On initial page load, POST will be empty.

Comment: Yes, POST is empty on initial load. However upon the 1st form submit POST is not empty as evidenced by the Quantity variable becoming set from POST. The problem is the Value variable remains NULL despite the fact that Value is a function of Quantity and Ratio. A second form submit rectifies this. The 2 provided examples are functionally the same with the exception of using SESSION and the one using SESSION requires multiple submits to set the Value variables.

Comment: It shouldn't require a second submit. Once you submit the form, assuming you have your session_start() call at the top of your script, it should be available to use. You generally would not use the session value on the same page, the point is to save it for use on other pages/scripts, but once set it should be available to use.

Comment: It seems your method if setting each index in $_SESSION individually works over my method of performing the array function as one contiguous block. I'm still not entirely sure why this is but I can adopt this practice moving forward.

Comment: Your method didn't work because your were trying to get the session values for 'quantities' in the same statement in which you were setting them. :)